# Model for Distributed Database

Tags: database-design, fragmentation, distributed-databases

I want to design a model for a distributed database solution.

- Are there appropriate tools and approaches?
- How to include stereotypes for (horizontal) fragments?

Comment: Oftentimes the function or business logic drives the design model. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just need a model for my project. I have to show the databases and how the are linked together.

Comment: In the current state, this question is too broad. Could you provide more details on what you are doing, and perhaps what you have found so far in your research?

Comment: I have found these 2 models so far: http://train-srv.manipalu.com/wpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/clip-image002110.jpg and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/img/admin046.gif. I think, this is the way, I should do that. But unfortunately I still don't understand, what (horizontal) fragments are and how to implement them in the model.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for data models to start with, I'd recommend you take a look at: http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/index.htm

This is the most comprehensive list of data model examples that I found so far. In fact I have used some samples as starting point for some of my projects. These models won't show you how to take horizontal fragmentation into consideration, though.

Update:

You may consider these basic techniques for horizontal fragmentation*:

- Range Partitioning: Each fragment is assigned a different value range
- Value List: For each fragment a list of attribute values is given
- Hash Values: Applying a hash function to tuples, each fragment is
  responsible for a given hash range

*Source - [Distributed Database Systems: Fragmentation and Allocation](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/d5/teaching/ws10_11/dds/slides/DDS-2-print.pdf) by Katja Hose, Ralf Schenkel

Comment: Link only answers have limited utility (if the link dies then the answer is useless).  Can you add a summary of the content here?

Comment: As user @DTest observed, the question is too broad. According to user1170330's comment, he seems to be looking for data models. To quote him exactly (see question comment), "I  just need a model for my project. I have to show the databases and how the are linked together." The link I provided, as clearly stated in my second paragraph, will lead you to a page that shows you: "comprehensive list of data model examples".

Comment: ...and as I said, if the link dies or changes then the answer has no merit.  If the actual answer doesn't contain the answer, then it's not an answer ;)

Comment: The models in the first link are only ERD's (most of them at least).